# How to run emacs from choco without extra terminal window

Tags: windows, windows-10, terminal, emacs

I have Windows 10 and just installed Emacs from choco. If I run emacs from system search I've got two windows, powershell and emacs. How can I get rid of the terminal.

I also want to execute this:

```
 emacs -rv --no-splash
```

so I have black emacs, right now I have white. I think I need batch file that will run `start "emacs"` but this don't work and where emacs return nothing.

adding `emacs -rv --no-splash` to batch file don't work it keep displaying the command in a loop.

**EDIT**

It seems that this kind of work:

```
start "" "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\emacs.exe" "-rv" "--no-splash" > stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

the problem is that there is new terminal open with emacs icon and "Select" as title that don't go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another executable in choco directory, this works:

```
 runemacs.exe "-rv" "--debug-init" "--no-splash"
```

inside bat file